# Azure Translator API always gives me 404

Tags: azure, microsoft-translator

I'm trying to use translator API through a free trial subscription. After creating it, I set resource groups and add cognitive service to it. On that cognitive service page, I followed the "Quick Start" guide and got a pair of keys and ENDPOINT url.

Then I followed this document. It says an API key and endpoint are needed to use translator API. And I get them from RESOURCE MANAGEMENT>Keys and Endpoint section.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/cognitive-services/translator/quickstart-translate?pivots=programming-language-javascript

But I always get 404 status code from this API every time I send a request. Is there anything I do wrong? How can I use this API?

SubscriptionID: zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz

My code:

```
 const subscriptionKey = 'my-sub-key'; // There are two keys, key1 and key2. I use key1 here.
 const endpoint = 'https://japaneast.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/';
 const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        baseUrl: endpoint,
        url: 'translate',
        qs: {
          'api-version': '3.0',
          'to': 'en'
        },
        headers: {
          'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscriptionKey,
          'Content-type': 'application/json',
          'X-ClientTraceId': uuidv4().toString()
        },
        body: [{
          'text': 'hello world'
        }],
        json: true,
 };
 request(options, function (err, resFromMicrosoft, body) {
        res.json(resFromMicrosoft);
}
```

Error response:

```
{
        "statusCode": 404,
        "body": {
            "error": {
                "code": "404",
                "message": "Resource not found"
            }
        },
        "headers": {
            "content-length": "56",
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "apim-request-id": "e2ae69cc-b93c-4db2-aef4-47096eb3ec61",
            "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload",
            "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
            "date": "Fri, 19 Jun 2020 06:11:24 GMT",
            "connection": "close"
        },
        "request": {
            "uri": {
                "protocol": "https:",
                "slashes": true,
                "auth": null,
                "host": "japaneast.api.cognitive.microsoft.com",
                "port": null,
                "hostname": "japaneast.api.cognitive.microsoft.com",
                "hash": null,
                "search": "?api-version=3.0&to=en",
                "query": "api-version=3.0&to=en",
                "pathname": "/translate",
                "path": "/translate?api-version=3.0&to=en",
                "href": "https://japaneast.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/translate?api-version=3.0&to=en"
            },
            "method": "POST",
            "headers": {
                "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": "my-sub-key",
                "Content-type": "application/json",
                "X-ClientTraceId": "8eedf6f4-db0c-45cb-a95b-92a2797df067",
                "accept": "application/json",
                "content-length": 83
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the documentation, please use the global endpoint - https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/

Comment: I've already tried that, too. But only got 401 this time.

Answer (score 0):

I saw your comment about getting 401 after using the global endpoint.
You still need to use the global endpoint as mentioned by Swetha.

This might help https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/57430#event-3480744006

(From the above page)
"It looks like you are using a common cognitive service resource and a key. Most the services have moved to using an individual resource type and if you can create and use the translator resource the steps mentioned in the documentation should work as is."